# FastAPI on Google App Engine: Why am I getting duplicate cloud tasks?

Tags: google-app-engine, gunicorn, fastapi, uvicorn, google-cloud-tasks

I have deployed a FastAPI ML service to Google App Engine but it's exhibiting some odd behavior. The FastAPI service is intended to receive requests from a main service (via Cloud Tasks) and then send responses back. And that does happen. But it appears the route in the FastAPI service that handles these requests gets called four times instead of just once.

[image]

My assumption was that GAE, gunicorn, or FastAPI would ensure that the handler runs once per cloud task. But it appears that multiple workers, or some other issue in my config, is causing the handler to get called four times. Here are a few more details and some specific questions:

- The Fast API app is deployed to Google App Engine (flex) via `gcloud app deploy app.yaml`
- The `app.yaml` file includes `GUNICORN_ARGS: "--graceful-timeout 3540 --timeout 3600 -k gevent -c gunicorn.gcloud.conf.py main:app"`
- The `Dockerfile` in the FastAPI project root (which is used for the gcloud deploy) also includes the final command `gunicorn -c gunicorn.gcloud.conf.py main:app`

Here's the gunicorn conf:

```
bind = ":" + os.environ["PORT"]
workers = multiprocessing.cpu_count() * 2 + 1
worker_class = "uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker"
forwarded_allow_ips = "*"
max_requests = 1000
max_requests_jitter = 100
timeout = 200
graceful_timeout = 6000
```

So I'm confused:

- Does `GUNICORN_ARGS` in `app.yaml` or the `gunicorn` argument in the Dockerfile take precedence?
- Should I be using multiple workers or is that precisely what's causing multiple tasks?

Happy to provide any other relevant info.

Answer (score 2):

GAE Flex defines environment variables in the app.yaml file [1].
Looking at Docker Compose "In the case of environment, labels, volumes, and devices, Compose “merges” entries together with locally-defined values taking precedence." [2], depending on if they are using a .env file "Values in the shell take precedence over those specified in the .env file." [3]

[1] https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml#defining_environment_variables
[2] https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/
[3] https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/

The issue is unlikely to be a Cloud Task duplication issue "in production, more than 99.999% of tasks are executed only once." [4]. You can investigate the calling source

[4] https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/common-pitfalls#duplicate_execution

You can also investigate the log contents to see if there are unique identifiers, or if they are the same logs.

For the second question on uvicorn [0] workers, you can try hard coding the value of “workers” to 1 and verify if there is no repetition.

[0] https://www.uvicorn.org/